# How to initialize an empty array and push items into it?

Tags: solidity, arrays

Here's my function:

```
function Test() constant returns (uint[]) {
   var myArray = uint[];
   myArray.push(123); 
   return myArray;
}
```

Here's an error I get in the [solidity online compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/):

> ballot.sol:25:9: Error: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(uint256[] memory)
>           myArray.push(123);

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to use an array in **storage** because [it is not possible to resize memory arrays](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays).

```
contract D { 
    uint[] myArray;
    function Test() constant returns (uint[]) {
       myArray.push(123); 
       return myArray;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you need to define the size of the array during initialization:

```
contract C {
    function f(uint len) {
        uint[] memory a = new uint[](7);
        bytes memory b = new bytes(len);
        // Here we have a.length == 7 and b.length == len
        a[6] = 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I get it now, thank you for your time and knowledge!

Comment: It was so simple I completely missed it

Comment: If we need a memory array inside a function, but wen don't know the items count, what can we do? Thank you!

Comment: @Suge I suggest asking a separation question with more details and be careful to avoid https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4):

You could define the array with the length of the array you want to filter. Problem is all the tail of empty elements.

```
uint[] memory filteredArray = new uint[](fullArray.length);
a[0] = 1;
```