# Declaratively creating an array of structs with one statement in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, struct, modifiers

I want to create a modifier that accepts a dynamic array, like this:

```
modifier parameterizedTest(Set[] memory sets) {
    // ...
}
```

Where the `Set` struct is defined like this:

```
struct Set {
    uint256 x;
    uint256 y;
    uint256 expected;
}
```

Now, I know that [normally](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11533/24693) one has to use multiple statements to define the  array, like this:

```
Set[] memory sets = new Set[](1);
sets.push(Set(1,2,3));
```

But is there any way to "shortcut" that approach? Ideally, I would like to pass my arrays declaratively to the modifier, like this:

```
function testSomething() external parameterizedTest([Set(1,2,3)]) {
    // ...
}
```

I know that the code above does not compile. I wrote it just for demonstrational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, that syntax is not yet supported. It may be supported in the future.

Take a look at this code snippet:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract Counter {

    uint256[] ints = [1,2,3]; // This syntax for value-type is supported

    bytes[] bs = [bytes("")]; // Works

    string[] strs = ["one", "two"]; // Works

    // uint256[][] = [[1,2,3]]; // Does not work

    // Set[] sets = [Set(1,2,3)]; // This syntax is not yet supported for structs because `Set(1,2,3)` is considered to be in memory and it cannot be assigned to storage like this

    struct Set {
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
        uint256 expected;
    }

    modifier parameterizedTest(Set[] memory sets) {
        // ...
        _;
    }

    function testSomething(Set[] memory _sets) external parameterizedTest(_sets) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

There's a shorthand way of declaring state arrays and assign values at the same time, but it does not work for arrays of structs since a statement like this `Set(1,2,3)` is considered to be in memory and it cannot be assigned from storage.

If your `testSomething` function receives the `Set[] memory _sets`, then you can certainly pass it to the modifier, as I showed in the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I cannot pass an array directly to `testSomething`, because I'm using Foundry. If I did that define an array as an argument, Foundry would fuzz the inputs, whereas I need to use pre-defined values.